# Django count() with a prefetch_related query seems not to work

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am working in a Django project and I could not get to work the count() function with Prefetch.

I have 20 orders but only 17 has its payout='available'. If I try to get the count() after filter inside a Prefetch Query:

```
order = Order.objects.filter(vendors__in=[vendor.id], is_ordered= True).order_by('-created_at')

promise_ordered_products_orders = order.prefetch_related(
Prefetch(
  'orderedproductorders',
    queryset = OrderedProduct.objects.filter(product__vendor__id=vendor.id, payout='available')
)        
)
print(promise_ordered_products_orders.count())
```

I get 20 orders as the count() function result i.e all orders. But it should be only 17.

I already manage to solve it with for loop to a list =[] and len().

I was wondering if there is anyway to get count() to work inside for the 'orderedproductordes'  and not for all orders in the Prefetch Query.